# How to get cmd query output to SQL Server Database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, cmd, netstat

I am trying to get `Netstat`count in`cmd`using

> ```
> netstat -anp tcp | find "80" /c
> ```

My question is that, How can I get that count updated in `MS SQL Server` database?

OR

I will be exporting that count to a file such as`.txt`. But how can I export that file data in`SQL Server`.

Comment: use BULK INSERT to import the text file

Comment: Works fine...thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about xp_cmdshell:

```
declare @tbl table (output int)
insert into @tbl (output)
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'netstat -anp tcp | find "80" /c'
select * from @tbl where output is not null
```

Returns (for example):

```
output
15
```

Comment: what if I want to put that value in perticular table of perticular database, how can I do so?

Comment: @adj009 See my edit - this is how you'd insert the value in table tbl, column output.